# Integrating a company web page and access to web apps once signed in - best practices / great examples?

Tags: interaction-design, navigation, web-app, web

Some companies, like Fitbit, integrate the corporate web site and their apps seamlessly and allow the users to navigate between the two experiences - the official company web site and personal Fitbit experience. The Corporate site is more targeted to new customers, where as the content when you are logged in is more targeted for existing customers/users.

I wonder if someone would have good examples of other sites that do this successfully, or perhaps some best practices for how to this or common pitfalls to share?

In the Fitbit web site, when the users are not logged in, they can only browse the official company web site and buy products. After creating a free account and logging in, they enter a personal space, which is your personalized Fitbit experience with various apps, like food diaries, weight management, etc. The users can seamlessly navigate between the Company web-site and personal experience with very simplified navigation. This example is in www.fitbit.com

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach I've seen is the authenticated portal model.

The corporate site (http://) is clearly targeted to acquiring new customers and integrates things like lead generation and new user sign up forms.

There is a link in the top right corner to "Log In", which acts as a portal to the https site.

A good example is CRM-like site Handshakez.com (pictured below). When you click "Log In", you are pointed to app.handshakez.com, versus handshakez.com which is the corporate site. Hope this helps!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen two approaches.

1. I have worked before on a web app as well as browsed other web apps where the clicking on the main logo in top left corner returns you to the *https:// - logged in home page*.  Beside the main logo is a small link to go to *http:// - not logged in home page*.
2. Clicking on the logo always links to http:// - homepage no matter if logged in or not.

These answers don't really answer your best practices question.  I'll try to find examples.